# Vue conditional css does not always trigger

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue application and in a page I added a loader since the graph I'm drawing in the page takes quite a while to display. This is the structure:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="changeLocalLoader">test</button>
        <div style="" :class="{test : localLoader}">
            <loader></loader>
        </div>
        <div ref="distribution" class="distribution-plot"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the changeLocalLoader method:

```
methods: {
    changeLocalLoader() {
        this.localLoader = !this.localLoader;
    },
},
```

Then, when I have to draw the graph I do the following:

```
        const drawGraph = function drawGraph(d) {
            this.changeLocalLoader();
            // building the graph
            ....
            // finishing building the graph
            this.changeLocalLoader();
        }
```

The css property I add (the "test" class) simply add position absolute and a dark background to the loader hence covering the graph div.
The problem now is that if I trigger that behavior with the test button I can see the graph being covered and displaying again if I click the button a second time, but if I let the draw graph function change the value of the localLoader property, nothing change.
The timing of the localLoader variables are okay (I console.log them) and I can't really understand what's wrong with that code.

EDIT:
the const drawGraph is been called thanks to this watcher:

```
xKey() {
    this.resizeListener();
},
```

that call resizeListener that call drawGraph every axis change and it's also called in the beginning to display the first graph. The value of the loader are correct in the console

Comment: why not use v-if/v-show for the div around the loader? By default not show it, when rendering the graph set v-if/v-show to true and give the div its test class.

Comment: v-if/v-else does not work at all with the graph, it hides only the axis and not the actual data.

Comment: How do you call `drawGraph`? Is the value of `this.localLoader` what you expect at each console.log?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. The issue was that the graph was processing too much data and the render just stopped working. That's why when I triggered the loader with the button (with no graph being processed) it was okay.

What I have done is to add a conditional class that modify the z-index of the loader and just put it above everything during the graph rendering.